# How to design a database that deals with several elements?

Tags: sql, database

I want to make an website like this:

Purpose: Several users will vote to choose a restaurant to go.

1. A user (poll-creator) makes a poll that includes several restaurants.
2. That user and other users (voters) vote to those candidates.
3. Check the result.

For this, I designed a simple database like this:

TABLE NAME: users

```
id - integer
username - varchar
display_name - varchar
password - varchar
birthdate - datetime
```

TABLE NAME: restaurants

```
id - integer
restaurant_name - varchar
category(asian, italian, etc) - varchar
description - varcahr
```

TABLE NAME: polls

```
id - integer
poll_name - varchar
candidates => ???
???
```

And then I found a problem. How should I design this 'polls' table? It should have a data like: restaurants that are candidates of this poll, result of the poll, ...

I have no idea how to design this... please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need master table for `POLLS` and then you can have mapping table between `POLLS - RESTAURANT`, and then `POLL_RESTAURANT - USER` to capture polls given by the voters as follows:

**POLLS**

```
poll_id         - integer
poll_name       - varchar
poll_created_by - integer (FK --> user_id of the user who created the POLL)
```

**POLL_RESTAURANTS**

```
poll_restaurant_id - integer
poll_id            - integer
restaurant_id      - integer
```

**USER_VOTES**

```
user_vote_id       - integer
poll_restaurant_id - integer (FK - poll to specific restaurant)
vote               - varchar (Y/N OR integer - 1/0 based on vote given by voter user)
```

**Note:** I tried using normalized design, Please add additional columns as per your requirements.

Comment: If this answer resolved the issue, Please accept it so that your question is considered as a closed one.